# What's an appropriate banality rating for the Imbued?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

In the old World of Darkness game *Changeling: the Dreaming*, no specific banality rating is given for hunters (as in *Hunter: the Reckoning*). Is there a more appropriate rating than the standard human rating of 6–7? If so, what is it, and what is a lore justification for it?

Comment: @Jeremiah: Why the tag edit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd put the typical hunter at around 5. The insights of the Messengers provide enough of a crack in the perceptions of the Imbued that the possibilities of the Dreaming can come through. Also, on a game level, being able to interact with the Kithain without driving them into slumber is important for the hunt.